# Item detail in grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to get the data from textbox in datagridview on button click, so I wrote the code below, but it is giving an error:

> obect reference not set to an instance of an object

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox3.Text;
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox4.Text;
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox5.Text;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You realize that you are *replacing* the same column on each loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

Instance of `this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow` is `null`

Add checking for null before using `CurrentRow`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow == null)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox3.Text;
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox4.Text;
        this.dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = textBox5.Text;
    }
}
```

And as @Alex mentioned in the comments in this code you setting three values in the same cell, so last value overwrite previous values